# Gloudemans shoppingcart Quantity Update Problem

Tags: laravel, cart, shopping-cart

When Update quantity properly Updated Every Row But First Row Not Updated.

When Click for update first row

Show this url:

http://localhost/onlineshop/cart?_token=2OQRpWg1l1I2YxHibXBGiNLESdjvWr8XWn9c3zeB&qty=2&row_id=3d59eb85d84a81848896f2917de23577#

Comment: Localhost links will not when posted to a forum. You need to have a publicly published website.

Comment: i know. the will not be given for open. just for understand

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

My update form inside another form. I just remove outside form and its work

Answer (score 0):

if your targeted form has under another form then this type of error happens.So first of all remove your parent form tag then it will work.thanks